# Como guardar un dato que sea persistente con AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo este script pero no se que debo de poner para guardar el dato

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".celda").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("bg-color");
        var currentColor =  $(this).attr("data-statuscolor");

        if(currentColor === "white"){
            newColor = "red";
        }else{
            newColor = "white";
        }
        $(this).attr("data-statuscolor", newColor);

        //enviar el nuevo color para persistencia en el backend
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ejemplo.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: {newColor: newColor}, //el newColor de la izquierda es el nombre que recibirás en tu script php, el newcolor de la derecha es el valor de la variable
            success: function(response){
                    //tu archivo de persistencia debe responder algo, en este ejemplo se supone que si responde exito el dato se guardo/actualizo de lo contrario ocurrió un error
                    if(response === 'exito'){
                        alert('Se actualizo el nuevo color!');
                    }else{
                        alert('Ocurrio un error al guardar el nuevo color');
                    }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

ejemplo.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION["newColor"] = $_POST["newColor"];

    ?>
```

Comment: Intenta poner el data asi: `data: {"newColor": newColor},`

Comment: Para guardarlo donde?

Comment: Como dato persistente en ejemplo.php o en la misma pagina

Comment: Puedes usar $_SESSION["newColor"] = $_POST["newColor"]; y recuerda inicializar en cada php que quieras recuperar el valor las sesiones con session_start();

Comment: No me esta guardando los datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te lo solucionaré de dos pasos. El primero, corrige tu llamada AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'ejemplo.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: "newColor="+newColor,
            success: function(response){
                    if(response === 'exito'){
                        alert('Se actualizo el nuevo color!');
                    }else{
                        alert('Ocurrio un error al guardar el nuevo color');
                    }
            }
        });
```

En tu back-end, como ya te mencionaron, puedes almacenar la variable durante una sesión de PHP de la siguiente forma.

#### ejemplo.php

```
session_start();

$_SESSION["newColor"] = filtrarVariable($_POST["newColor"]);

function filtrarVariable($v){
   $v = htmlspecialchars($v);
   return $v;
}
```

Nunca olvides filtrar la información que el usuario pasa a la aplicación. Te evitarás muchos defectos de seguridad.

Con ésto, podrás acceder a la variable `$_SESSION['newColor']` desde cualquier archivo PHP en tu servidor mientras llames la función `session_start()` al inicio de el fichero.

**PHP y filtrado de variables:**

https://blog.tednologia.com/seguridad-php-filtrar-numeros-cadenas/

Comment: Muchas grcias, ya lo monte pero sigue sin guardar osea recargo la pagina y los cambios no se guardan

Comment: Estás llamando ``session_start()`` en el fichero donde lo guardas y donde lo quieres leer?

Comment: Si, pero nada estoy pensando trabajarlo con LocalStorage